# Looking for a clustering algorithm, that can cluster by density around a centroid, but with a fixed maximum distance cutoff

Tags: python, machine-learning, coordinates, cluster-analysis, k-means

I currently have a list with 3D coordinates which I want cluster by density into a unknown number of clusters.  In addition to that I want to score the clusters by population and by distance to the centroids.
I would also like to be able to set a maximum possible distance from a certain centroid. Ideally the centroid represent a  point of the data-set, but it is not absolutely necessary. I want to do this for a list ranging from  approximately 100 to 10000 3D coordinates.

So for example, say i have a point [x,y,z] which could be my centroid:
Points that are closest to x,y,z should contribute the most to its score (i.e. a logistic scoring function like y = (1 + exp(4*(-1.0+x)))** -1 ,where x represents the euclidean distance to point [x,y ,z] 
( https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1+%2B+exp(4(-1.0%2Bx)))**+-1 )

Since this function never reaches 0, it is needed to set a maximum distance, e.g. 2 distance units to set a limit to the cluster.

I want to do this until no more clusters can be made, I am only interested in the centroid, thus it should preferably be a real datapoint instead of an interpolated one it also has other properties connected to it.

I have already tried DBSCAN from sklearn, which is several orders of magnitude faster than my code, but it does obviously not accomplish what I want to do

Currently I am just calculating the proximity of every point relative to all other points and am scoring every point by the number and distance to its neighbors (with the same scoring function discussed above), then I take the highest scored point and remove all other, lower scored, points that are within a certain cutoff distance. It gets the job done and is accurate, but it is too slow.

I hope I could be somewhat clear with what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the neighbor search function of sklearn to find points within the maximum distance 2 fast. Only do this *once* compute the logistic weights only once.

Then do the remainder using ony this precomputed data?